# Symfony 4: Var-dumper not working properly

Tags: php, symfony, twig, bundle, var-dump

I tried to use the wonderful dump function from the var-dumper bundle in symfony 4 and for some reason I get the following error:

Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "vendor\symfony\var-dumper\Dumper\AbstractDumper.php" at line 181.

Additionally, when I try to use the {% dump foo %} tag in a twig template I get an error:

Unknown "dump" tag.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `dump` is not a tag, it's a function. So change `{% dump foo %}` into `{% dump(foo) %}`

Comment: Quoting from https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/debug.html: {% dump foo.bar %} is the way to go when the original template output shall not be modified: variables are not dumped inline, but in the web debug toolbar;

Comment: Also if you want to use dump function in twig template you should use {{ dump(foo) }}, not {% dump(foo) %}

Comment: Oh, you are right about the `dump` tag. And yeah, my bad, I meant to say `{{ dump(foo) }}`. – Have you installed `symfony/var-dumper` or `symfony/debug-bundle`? See https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html#installation

Comment: Yes I did, I can use dump in php and then exit, it works as expected, but not in the cases above (that are showcases in documentation)

Comment: symfony/var-dumper is automagically disabled on production environment. Check your symfony environment.

Comment: As I said before, I can use dump function in php (when exit after this) and works just fine, so my environment is definitely dev, not doubt about it. So it is something else, nothing so obvious

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A guy named Simon Waldburger mentioned in the lesson's comments that installing "debug" fixed the issue (it fixed it for me). The instruction was in the next lesson.

```
composer require debug --dev
```

iiirxs is also correct, to output dump in twig file, do

```
{{ dump(variable) }}
```

Comment: In fact. Worked. Twig needs symfony/debug-bundle to be installed in order to work from inside twig tempates. Thank You!!

Comment: Worked for symfony 5.4 and Symfony 6.3