# Symfony 4.1 dump doesn't work

Tags: symfony, twig, dump

I just installed the Symfony 4.1, the dump function doesn't work on controller but it works on twig files, if I remove the symfony/debug-bundle, then the dump works correctly in controller but it doesn't work in twig properly, it acts like simple var_dump.
Does any body have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Paste your controller code here

Comment: It's just a simple dump.

Comment: Well i didn't have enough reputation to comment this post but contrary to what others comment imply, this bug [a has been confirmed](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/27622) and apperently it should be fixed by this commit https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/27614

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48304155/symfony-4-var-dumper-not-working-properly

Answer (score 1):

Symfony have new features for dump.
Now dump shown in symfony profiler.
Please check proper. In symfony profiler

Answer (score 1):

This problem is fixed with symfony 4.1.1, https://github.com/symfony/symfony/releases/tag/v4.1.1

dd() in controller work after upgrate to 4.1.1 with composer "php composer update".

Answer (score 0):

Just be careful, if you use dump in controller, then you should have [WebProfilerBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/web_profiler.html) installed as well. Then you see output inside of that toolbar and not in page content.

Comment: I have WebProfiler and yes I see the dump result in profiler, but I think it should work in page too, because if put die after dump it will not work, also there is new command dd in 4.1, which is dump and die, it does not work either.

Comment: Normally dump called outside of view {{ }} will collect its output and then put it to WebProfiler and doesn't output it to the page. If you wanna output in for example from controller, then you really need to put die/exit after or use `dd`

Comment: I don't have same problem with Symfony 4, I installed profiler and debug pack for it and it works well in both twig and controller, and as I mentioned dd is dump and die so there is no need to put die.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just now and the other answers here were not relevant.  If you look to the Profiler Bar, the "crosshairs(debug)" icon will show your dump from twig only (sometimes).

To see ALL dumps, you sometimes need to go track them down in the "Ajax Requests" part.  To do this, click the Ajax Requests in the Symfony Profiler bar at the bottom of the screen.  Then click the lines until you see a AJAX request that fired and has your dump.

The reason why only your Twig dump showed up is that the profiler bar is mostly about the primary request. The suppression is an ajax secondary request. The dump you asked about was in the ajax not the primary request.