# Twig template dump function's output has no style

Tags: php, symfony, twig

When I was working on an older project (Symfony 3.2), the `{{ dump(var) }}` in twig templates was displaying just fine (with style and expand/collapse capabilities). But on my recent project (Symfony 4), the `dump` function in twig is displaying the text only.

I looked in the docs, GitHub issues for both Symfony and Twig and in SO without any success.

Docs:

- [Symfony - How to Dump Debug Information in Twig Templates](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/debug.html)
- [Twig - Dump function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/dump.html)

Is there anything that have changed which I didn't see?

**Edit**: I got the desired result using `dump()` in PHP (got the syntax color & collapse/expand), but I still don't understand why it is not working for twig like it is in older Symfony version. I must be missing something...

Comment: Are u perhaps working on another server as well, which does not has [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) installed?

Comment: @DarkBee, it's on the same environment (local). Only the projects creation differs.

Comment: When looking for the Twig documentation, it says that you do not need to add the `<pre>` tag if you activated xdebug. In fact, just using `{{ dump() }}` does create the `<pre>` tag by itself (so you get readable lines instead of one big block), so I guess it's fine on the xdebug side?

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: @goto No, not a single line.

Comment: Does the symfony/var-dumper component is enabled ?

Comment: @candybeer Looking ATM, and I see that the package is listed in composer `conflict` section.

Comment: @candybeer Can you please add your comment as an answer so I can award you with the bounty? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @candybeer for leading me on the way to go.

Just add the `debug-pack` package to the project (which includes the `symfony\debug-bundle`):

`composer require debug --dev`

**Or**

Simply add the `debug-bundle` which is required as said in the other SO question comments:

`composer require symfony/debug-bundle`

---

Found in this SO question:
[Symfony 4: Var-dumper not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48304155/symfony-4-var-dumper-not-working-properly?rq=1) :

The `dump()`was not working in twig and was throwing an error, but the answer told to also install the debug package, which made it work for the OP. Giving it a try myself, I am now able to dump via twig with the standard style and ability to collapse/expand nodes.

Like said in the comments (and in the [var-dumper documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html#installation)), the `var-dumper` package requires the `debug-bundle` package to work in symfony.

Once again, many thanks to you @candybeer!

Comment: Same problem and the installation of `symfony/debug-bundle` has resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

As specified in the doc,the component has to be installed before using it :

**Doc** : https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/debug.html

**Command** :

```
composer require symfony/debug
```

You've to check if it's well enabled..

Comment: Strange... Just tried your solution on another project, and yet, it didn't resolve the issue... tried the `composer require debug --dev` command, and it worked. I looked, and the `debug` is the `debug-pack` which include many other component such as the `symfony/debug-bundle`, `symfony/profiler-pack` and `symfony\var-dumper`. [Github - debug-pack](https://github.com/symfony/debug-pack/blob/master/composer.json)