# Warning: session_id(): Session ID cannot be changed after headers have already been sent

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a difficult problem with my project. In localhost environment everything works good, but after deploying on heroku I have an error as logged user:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Warning: session_id(): Session ID cannot be changed after headers have already been sent").

The problem is only on restaurant and comments twig files. After remowing user login check ({% if app.user %} ) everything works fine, but I need such options in my project.

```
Twig\Error\
RuntimeError
in templates/base.html.twig (line 102)
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">                
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>            
</button>            
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">                
  <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">                
  {% if app.user %}                
  <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('app_user_panel') }}">Panel&nbsp;użytkownika</a>
  {% endif %}                
  <a class="nav-link" href="/#aboutus">O&nbsp;nas</a>                
  <a id="login__button" class="nav-link" href="/{{app.user ? 'wyloguj' : 'logowanie'}}"                 
  @click="isOpen = false">
```

Link to my project: https://restrank.herokuapp.com/

Link to repository: https://github.com/GrzegorzWanat95/RestRank

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHPGQ.png)

I would be grateful for help. I have spend a lot of time to fix it, but I don't have idea. I saw that it was a common problem in PHP, but fixes don't work with Symfony 6.

---

Update:

I have notice that error is connected with controller function which display list of restaurants searched by name or city. In localhist server it works but after deployment fetching parameters from URL cause error.

Code of my controller which cause error after user login:

```
#[Route('/szukaj/{type}/{name}', name: 'app_restaurant_query_name', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
public function searchByName(RestaurantRepository $restaurantRepository, $type, $name)
{
$values = dump([$type, $name]);

switch ($type){
    case 1 :
        if($name == null){
            return $this->render('restaurant/index.html.twig', [
                'restaurants' => $restaurantRepository->findAll(),
            ]);
        }
        
        $restaurants = $restaurantRepository->findBy(
            ['Name' => $name]
        );
            return $this->render('restaurant/index.html.twig', [
                'restaurants' => $restaurants,
            ]);
        break;
    case 2 :
        if($name == null){
            return $this->render('restaurant/index.html.twig', [
                'restaurants' => $restaurantRepository->findAll(),
            ]);
        }
        $restaurants = $restaurantRepository->findBy(
            ['City' => $name]
        );
            return $this->render('restaurant/index.html.twig', [
                'restaurants' => $restaurants,
            ]);
        break;
    default: 
            return $this->render('restaurant/index.html.twig', [
                'restaurants' => $restaurantRepository ->findAll(),
            ]);
            break;
}
```

}

I don't know how to pass parameters from search by URL and avoid this error.

Comment: Did you try `{% if app.user|default %}`. This will make sure no error/notice is thrown when the user isn't defined

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have changed code as you said, but there is still the same error - now {% if app.user|default %} is higlighted in error communicate. 

What is interesting - templates depends on base.html.twig wchich have login option (top bar with menu). It don't cause error on home page (and relatet eg. regulations, contact) - only on sites related with database like restaurant index. I don't know why...

Answer (score 1):

The error was caused by dump function in restaurant controller.
After removing it everything works ok. It should be:

```
 $value = $request->query->get('Type');
 $name = $request->query->get('Name');
```

Comment: Apparently you also need to install the debug bundle to use the dump method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48477607/192961